# Configure one form to be floating while the rest are tabbed? MS Access 2016

Tags: microsoft-access, forms, microsoft-office-2016

I have an MS Access database that is currently configured to use "Tabbed Documents" as shown in the "Current Database" properties.  I like the appearance and cleanliness of tabbed documents but I'd like my initial login form to be a floating form.  Is it possible to individually specify this property on a per-form basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that the trick is to set the Pop-up property to Yes.